# Deep copying array in C... malloc?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an array in C (originalBoard being the copy):

```
int gy, gx;          
            for (gy=0; gy<9; gy++)
            {
                for (gx=0; gx<9; gx++)
                {                  
                g.originalBoard[gy][gx]=g.board[gy][gx];
                }
            }
```

This does not seem to be working out, and I'm guessing this is just making pointers to the original board array.

So would the solution be to try and use malloc? Like:

```
    int* g.originalBoard[9][9]=malloc(sizeof(g.board[9][9]));
```

btw this is a 9x9 two dimensional array. What would the syntax be (the compiler gives an error for the above line...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
 //assuming g.originalBoard is array of array of integers and same for g.board  
int *originalBoard = malloc(sizeof(g.board));
memcpy(originalBoard, g.board, sizeof(g.board));
```

Comment: memcopy is they way to go. I edited your answer because it needs to be sizeof(g.originalBoard), not g.board. I skip the malloc function here because I declared the array in a structure beforehand

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 no it is `g.board` as this what needs to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct place to use [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memcpy.html).  You probably want

```
g.originalBoard = (int *)malloc(9 * 9 * sizeof(int));
if (NULL == g.originalBoard) {
    /* malloc failed, so handle the error somehow */
}
memcpy(g.originalBoard, g.board, 9 * 9 * sizeof(int));
```

---

You may notice that in the above solution you have to use `g.board[r * 9 + c]` to access the item at index (r, c), rather than two indices.  This is because of the way this dynamically allocates memory - at compile-time `g.board` and `g.originalBoard` are just pointers, not arrays.  Alternatively, if you have control over the definition of the type of `g`, you can hardcode the size of the matrix as

```
struct foo {
    int board[9][9];
    int originalBoard[9][9];
    /* Other fields here */
};
```

Then you wouldn't have to malloc extra space for `g.board` and `g.originalBoard` - those two fields would be automatically allocated whenever you allocated space for `g` itself.  Also, you could use `g.board[r][c]` instead of `g.board[r * 9 + c]`.

Comment: I looked into memcpy before, doesn't matter that I'm copying array of integers not a string?

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 `memcpy` copies bytes and doesn't care about the type of data that those bytes comprise, so no it doesn't matter that you're copying integers.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you are trying to execute the following 'intended' task on the arrays,

int* g.originalBoard[9][9]=malloc(sizeof(g.board[9][9]));

then you should change the above line to

int* g.originalBoard[8][8]=malloc(sizeof(g.board[8][8]));

because this is a 9x9 two dimensional array and in C arrays are ZERO-based.